# bundle install - The Gemfile specifies no dependencies - Even though I'm in the directory that contains the Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rspec, gemfile

I'm trying to follow a guide to use rspec for testing. I use bundle init to create the Gemfile. Then I tried to do bundle install (following the guide) to install all the gems. I made sure to be in the same folder containing the gemfile. However, I keep getting this:

> The Gemfile specifies no dependencies
>
> Bundle complete! 0 Gemfile dependencies, 1 gem now installed.
>
> Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

My Gemfile (right after I did bundle init) looks like this:

> frozen_string_literal: true
>
> source "https://rubygems.org"
>
> git_source(:github) {|repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }
>
> gem "rails"

I use ruby 2.7.1.

Any help will be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this step by step and I get this error only when I haven't specified any gem in my Gemfile. I guess the bundle init command create a Gemfile with gem 'rails' line is commented. Please verify your Gemfile and make sure you have added at least one gem into your Gemfile or check if gem 'rails' line is still commented out.

Comment: Thank you. It is the problem. The "rail" line is still commented out when I did bundle init.